# Symfony 5 controller won't validate errors

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to migrate a some parts of a project made with Typescript + Express + Firebase to Symfony 5 and MySQL. But I don't get why the [ValidatorInterface](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) isn't working.

When I submit the form with unexpected characters (i.e.: a password with 3 charactesrs) it creates the user despites the [validation constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) assigned in the `User` entity. The only constraint validation that actually works despites it does not show any form errors, is the [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).

#### This is how my controller looks like:

```php
    /**
     * GET: Display form
     * POST: Creates a user
     * 
     * @Route("/users/crear", name="create_user", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function create_user(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $user = new User();

        // Form
        if ($request->isMethod('GET')) {
            $form = $this->createForm(CrearUserType::class, $user);
            return $this->render('user/create.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'errors' => []
            ]);
        }

        // Form submit
        $data = $request->request->get('create_user');
        $errors = [];

        $user->setName($data['name']);
        $user->setEmail($data['email']);
        $user->setPassword($data['password']);
        $user->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $user->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

        $form = $this->createForm(CrearUserType::class, $user);

        // Entity validation
        $errors = $validator->validate($user);        

        if (count($errors) > 0) { // This is always 0
            $user->setPassword('');
            return $this->render('user/create.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'user' => $user,
                'errors' => $errors
            ]);
        }

        try {
            $user->setPassword(password_hash($user->getPassword(), PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash(
                'success', 
                'User '.$user->getName().' has been saved.'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('users');
        } catch(\Exception $exception) {
            $user->setPassword('');
            $this->addFlash(
                'error', 
                'Server error: ' . $exception->getMessage()
            );
            return $this->render('user/create.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'user' => $user,
                'errors' => $errors
            ]);
        }
    }
```

#### And this is my entity:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Name is mandatory")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Email is mandatory")
     * @Assert\Email(
     *  message="Invalid email address"
     * )
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Password is mandatory")
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(
     *  value=6,
     *  message="The password has to be at least 6 chars long"
     * )
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(?string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So, any clues on what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you enabled the validation per [Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration) instructions, along with annotations option as well?

Comment: Might also consider following the form example in the docs.  At the very least you will reduce the number of lines in your action.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, yes, I have enabled annotations and validation itself in `framework.yaml`

Comment: @Cerad, I have used the `make:form` console command and then rendered it after passign it to the view with `{{ form(form) }}`

Comment: If it's saving to the database, I'm assuming at least the email is valid? For the password it may be worth to try [`Length`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html) instead of `GreaterThan`. What values are you submitting / what constraints aren't working?

Comment: @msg, I didn't think about that.. `GreaterThan...` is for numbers only... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of my response, because I never handle request with a ValidatorInterface. I use the handlerequest method provided by controller.

You created the form

```
 $form = $this->createForm(CrearUserType::class, $user);
```

But you forgot to handle request

```
 $form->handleRequest($request);
```

So your form does not validate data forwarded by request. Try to add this line just after the $form creation. Then, you can test that the user entity is valid with

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
 //no errors
}
//error exists
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. But still the only validation made was the unique entity, any other asserts are being ignored.